# Como salvar vários registros usando "for"

Tags: java, react, spring, jpa

Estou tentando salvar vários registros de acordo com a quantidade de datas selecionadas (um registro para cada data), usando a estrutura de repetição "for".

No entanto, independente da quantidade de datas selecionadas, é criado o registro apenas para a última data da lista. Segue o código:

```
@Override
    public Boolean salvar(DataFaltaSubstituicao dataFaltaSubstituicao) {
        
        List<String> faltas = dataFaltaSubstituicao.getListaDataFaltas();
        
        System.out.println(faltas.size());
        
        for (String data: faltas) {
            
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
            LocalDate dataFormatada = LocalDate.parse(data, formatter);
            
            dataFaltaSubstituicao.setDataFalta(dataFormatada);
            
            dataFaltaSubstituicaoRepository.save(dataFaltaSubstituicao);
            
            System.out.println("Data: " + dataFormatada);
            
        }   
        
        System.out.println("Passou aqui!");
        
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }
```

Obrigado senhores pelas respostas, realmente era isso, em todas as iterações, a mesma instância do objeto estava sendo manipulada. Segue o código com a correção:

```
@Override
    public Boolean salvar(DataFaltaSubstituicao dataFaltaSubstituicao) {
        
        List<String> faltas = dataFaltaSubstituicao.getListaDataFaltas();
        
        System.out.println(faltas.size());
        
        for (String data: faltas) {
            
            DataFaltaSubstituicao dfSub = new DataFaltaSubstituicao();
            
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
            LocalDate dataFormatada = LocalDate.parse(data, formatter);
            
            dfSub.setDataFalta(dataFormatada);
            dfSub.setLancamentoServidor(dataFaltaSubstituicao.getLancamentoServidor());
            dfSub.setHorasFaltas(dataFaltaSubstituicao.getHorasFaltas());
            dfSub.setTipoFalta(dataFaltaSubstituicao.getTipoFalta());
            
            dataFaltaSubstituicaoRepository.save(dfSub);
            
            System.out.println("Data: " + dataFormatada);
            
        }   
        
        System.out.println("Passou aqui!");
        
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }
```

Comment: Provavelmente você está atualizando o mesmo registro, acredito que esteja usando o hibernate. Quando o sistema salva o primeiro teu objeto ganha um ID e ao salvar os demais ele vai fazendo update não insert. Para confirmar, recomendo debugar e verificar se realmente está recebendo um ID ou não e também é possível configurar o hibernate para printar nos logs as quais ele usou.

Answer (score -1):

O erro acontece porque a instância da classe é a mesma.

**Por isso, só é salvo uma vez!**

Neste caso, você deve criar uma nova instância da classe **DataFaltaSubstituicao** para cada iteração do comando ***for***.

```
public class TestResource {

private final SaleRepository saleRepository;

public TestResource(SaleRepository saleRepository) {
    this.saleRepository = saleRepository;
}

@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<SaleDto> test() {

    Costumer thiago = Costumer.of("Thiago", LocalDate.of(1986, Month.NOVEMBER, 7), GenderEnum.MALE);

    Product bola = Product.of("Bola", BigDecimal.valueOf(50));
    Product televisao = Product.of("Televisão", BigDecimal.valueOf(2000));
    Product mesaDeJantar = Product.of("Mesa de Jantar", BigDecimal.valueOf(3000));
    Product laptop = Product.of("Laptop", BigDecimal.valueOf(7000));

    Sale sale = Sale.of(thiago, Arrays.asList(bola, televisao, mesaDeJantar, laptop));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        saleRepository.save(sale);
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok(SaleDto.parse(sale));
}}
```

### O resultado do código acima é:

Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence

Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence

Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence

Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence

Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence

Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence

Hibernate: insert into costumer (birth_date, gender, name, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into sale (costumer_id, date_of_sale, id) values (?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into product (name, price, sale_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into product (name, price, sale_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into product (name, price, sale_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into product (name, price, sale_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### Analisando o log do hibernate

Veja que por mais que o comando for itere 10x não há atualização, ou seja, não houve **update** como foi sugerido em outra resposta.

### Possível Solução

```
public class TestResource {


private final SaleRepository saleRepository;

public TestResource(SaleRepository saleRepository) {
    this.saleRepository = saleRepository;
}

@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<SaleDto>> test() {
    List<SaleDto> saved = new ArrayList<>();

    Costumer thiago = Costumer.of("Thiago", LocalDate.of(1986, Month.NOVEMBER, 7), GenderEnum.MALE);

    Product bola = Product.of("Bola", BigDecimal.valueOf(50));
    Product televisao = Product.of("Televisão", BigDecimal.valueOf(2000));
    Product mesaDeJantar = Product.of("Mesa de Jantar", BigDecimal.valueOf(3000));
    Product laptop = Product.of("Laptop", BigDecimal.valueOf(7000));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Sale savedSale = saleRepository.save(Sale.of(thiago, Arrays.asList(bola, televisao, mesaDeJantar, laptop)));
        saved.add(SaleDto.parse(savedSale));
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok(saved);
}}
```

### Resultado do código acima:

Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence

Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence

Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence

Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence

Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence

Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence

Hibernate: insert into costumer (birth_date, gender, name, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into sale (costumer_id, date_of_sale, id) values (?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into product (name, price, sale_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into product (name, price, sale_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into product (name, price, sale_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into product (name, price, sale_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence

Hibernate: insert into sale (costumer_id, date_of_sale, id) values (?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence

Hibernate: insert into sale (costumer_id, date_of_sale, id) values (?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence

Hibernate: insert into sale (costumer_id, date_of_sale, id) values (?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence

Hibernate: insert into sale (costumer_id, date_of_sale, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence

Hibernate: insert into sale (costumer_id, date_of_sale, id) values (?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence

Hibernate: insert into sale (costumer_id, date_of_sale, id) values (?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence

Hibernate: insert into sale (costumer_id, date_of_sale, id) values (?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence

Hibernate: insert into sale (costumer_id, date_of_sale, id) values (?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence

Hibernate: insert into sale (costumer_id, date_of_sale, id) values (?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

Hibernate: update product set name=?, price=?, sale_id=? where id=?

---

### Analisando o log

Veja que agora houveram dez ***inserts*** de Vendas, um ***insert*** Cliente e quarenta ***updates*** de Produtos.

### Finalizando

Ainda assim, é uma implementação ruim, esses 40 updates de produtos acontece porque o produto é o mesmo, e não deveria ser implementado dessa maneira. Apenas demostrei como seu código estava se comportando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Documentação EntityManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist-java.lang.Object-)